# I can not read data from jar

Tags: java, jar

structure of project
[image: structure of project]

Code:

```
public class WriterXlsx {
    public WriterXlsx(String sfilename, List<RecordNameCode> records, List<Day> recordsDay, Integer fullTime) {
        String path = "res/" + sfilename + ".xlsx";
        URL resURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
        try (InputStream inputStream = resURL.openStream())
        {
            int lastUsedColumn = createListHead().size();
            XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

            drawRecordHead(createListHead(),sheet);
            writeContent(2, records,sheet);
            createPlanForDay(recordsDay,fullTime,lastUsedColumn,sheet,workBook);

            try(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\student3\\"+sfilename+".xlsx"); ) {
            workBook.write(out);
            out.close();         }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Program will write to SfileName and read from file in `res\` IDE(Intellij IDEA), but it doesn't work independently.
I can't start program by .jar archieve. (maybe res directory not found)..

MANIFEST:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: workhere.Start
```

Class Start:

```
public class Start {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("It's working");
        new Start().start(countDays);
        System.out.println("Work is finished");
    }
........
```

Comment: shar if you have any error , exception?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" : does it throw an exception? What kind, from which line?

Comment: it works fine in IDE, but doesn't work by .jar
0 exception and errors

Comment: @Joni at the end of it must create file, and jar must be runnable

Comment: Ah so the problem is that you can't start the program? Is the `workhere.Start` class included in the .jar file and does it have a public static void method called `main`? How is the code you have included in the question is related to the problem?

Comment: @Joni are you kidding me? i already have `public static void main` in my Start class

Comment: And what happens when you try to start the program with the .jar file? How do you try to start it? Are you using Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are using `.getResource()` Try

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

instead of

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
```

Once the file is packaged into a jar, it ceases to be a stand alone file on the filesystem which an exclusive filesystem path. There is just one file, the jar and you file is its content.

Comment: i have no idea, which Class i should use, therefore  i asked you for help

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in differents ways to test, for example:

```
this.getClass().getResource(sfilename)
```

getResources find the resource relative to the package.

```
this.getClass().getResource("/"+sfilename)
```

getResources will treat it as an absolute path and simply call the classloader.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(sfilename)
```

The reason you can't use a / in the ClassLoader path is because all ClassLoader paths are absolute and so / is not a valid first character in the path.